# Auto scroll iframe window during StreamingHttpresponse

Tags: html, css, django

I've got a StreamingHttpResponse function that I am running inside of a iframe child the code for the iframe is below. The iframe, and function is working properly but the function sometimes returns a very long output and you either need to hold down "page down" or constantly use mouse wheel to see the latest and greatest output. I'd like for it to automatically scroll when html/text is received in the browser.

I believe I might be restricted by an html or css solution? I'm not sure if jQuery or Javascript of some sort will process properly in the StreamingHttpResponse which is why I included Django as a related framework. I've tried a div style overflow auto scroll solution without success.

Here's the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="{% url 'landingpage' %}" frameBorder="0" 
name="botframe3" scrolling="yes" style="position: absolute; height: 70%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Here's the StreamingHttpResponse call:

```
@condition(etag_func=None)
def stageDevice(request, cmd, pk):
    pullID = Pull.objects.filter(pk=pk)[0]
    pullIDq = Pull.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    emailListqc = EmailList.objects.filter(ccqc='yes')
    emailListstg = EmailList.objects.filter(ccstg='yes')
    reqUser = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(runSetup(pullID, pullIDq, reqUser), content_type='text/html')
```

Here's the runSetup function:

```
def runSetup(pullID, pullIDq, reqUser):
    yield "<html><head><title>Setup Phase</title>\n"
    yield "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/css/base.css'>\n"
    yield "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/css/style.css'>\n"
    yield "<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://bootswatch.com/4/cyborg/bootstrap.css'></head>\n"
    yield "<div>Attempting to setup for pull ID {0} - Store# {1}.</div>\n".format(pullID.pullid, pullID.store.storenumber)
    yield "<hr>"
    yield '<div style="overflow: auto;">'
        # Rest of the code goes here
    yield "</div></body></html>\n"
```

I'd like for the streaming html/text output to automatically scroll as it's being presented and then when the script finishes to stop and allow the user to scroll back up if desired.